# Split export format in bash

Tags: bash

Given a file with the following syntax:

```
export 'my_var1=value1' 'my_var2=value2' 'my_var3=value3'
export 'my_var3=value3' 'my_var4=value4'
```

Are there any way to split it in bash order to get the variables names?

```
my_var1
my_var2 
my_var3
```

I thought first spliting by line and then by space. But "values" can contain spaces. I think the key is in the quotes.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the context here? If your goal is to determine which variables a piece of code exports when run, I usually just record the list before executing it, execute it, and then compare the new list of variable names that are set. That's going to be a more robust approach anyhow -- it'll detect ways of exporting variables that just looking for the specific export command pattern doesn't match. (`declare -x var=value`, or `set -a; var=value; set +a` both are exports as well, f/e).

Comment: I agree, but the problem here is that we don't receive a list, but a file with this syntax directly because we get them from a remote service. The service should provide a better way but this is not the current issue. Thanks.

Comment: My intended point above was that you can easily **make** before and after lists yourself by asking the shell to dump its current list of variables before and after evaluating the code (assuming you trust the code enough to evaluate it -- but then, if you don't, that's where rbash comes in). You don't need to "receive" a list from anyone.

Comment: See https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash#L75-L101, a shell function that compares the list of variables defined before and after calling another function to check for namespace leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk works well for this, and is fairly easily readable.

```
awk -F "export '|' '|'$" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(split($i,arr,"=")==2)print arr[1]}}' file
```

Explanation:

`-F "export '|' '|'$"` - any of the three patterns (`export '`, `' '`, `'$`) are used to delimit each line.

`if(split($i,arr,"=")==2)print arr[1]` - for each token, delimit with `=`, if there are two tokens, then print the first.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments need to make '= the delimiter and handle when the value can have more than 2 tokens:

```
awk -F "export '|' '|'$" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(split($i,arr,"\x27=")!=0)print arr[1]}}' file
```

Comment: This is almost the solution, because getting the first token, where there are not spaces prevents that. But is printing a quote at the end of the name `my_var1'`

Comment: Make sure you're including all the single quotes and pipes in the `-F` argument.  Seems like you might be missing something there.  If not, please show us the line in the file that's printing the extra quote.

Comment: I am checking it with some special characters. What worked was: `awk -F "export '|' '|'$" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(split($i,arr,"\x27=")!=0)print arr[1]}}' file` . Added \x27 as token delimiter to avoid printing the final quote and !=0 because we can have 2 or more tokens in value.

Answer (score 0):

this one-liner works for the given example:

```
grep -oP "[^']*(?==)" f|awk '!a[$0]++'
```

It outputs:

```
my_var1
my_var2
my_var3
my_var4
```

The spaces in the "value" part is not an issue.

- The `grep` part extracts the variable names
- The `awk` part eliminates the duplicates.

Comment: This will fail if there are any `=`s in the value. Consider something like `my-var1=bzz=value1`; as is, it will report `my_var1=bzz` as a variable name. Replacing `*` with `*?` to do a non-greedy match will report `my_var1` and `bzz` as separate variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You could have bash do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export() { printf '%s\n' "${@%%=*}"; }
source ./yourfile
```

In this case, it would show

```
$ ./myscript
my_var1
my_var2
my_var3
my_var3
my_var4
```

This has the benefit of things like `export target="$HOSTNAME"` and other bash syntax working correctly, though obviously it will also run any command substitutions and therefore can't be used on untrusted files.

Answer (score 0):

with awk :

```
awk -F\' '{while((i+=2)<=NF){sub("=.*","",$i);print $i}}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one step with `-o`utput and `-P`erl options to grep.

```
$: grep -Po "(?<=')[[:alnum:]_]+?(?==)" file
my_var1
my_var2
my_var3
my_var3
my_var4
```

`(?<=')`is a *positive lookbehind* asserting that the pattern starts after a `'`.
`[[:alnum:]_]+?` is a character class match (`[...]`) for any series of **one or more** (`+`) *non-greedy* (`?`) alphanumerics *and/or* underscores (`[:alnum:]_`).
`(?==)` is a positive lookahead requiring the next character be an equal sign.

Pipe it through a `sort -u` or `uniq` to eliminate the dups if you like.